# Is there a way to run typeorm query builder without it loading the entity?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I have noticed that `typeorm` loads the specified entity when running query builder.

For example, if I run the following inside a migration.

```
await queryRunner.manager
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .insert()
      .into('users')
      .values({
        name: 'Testing',
        language: 'english',
      })
      .execute();
```

After this if I modify user table and add a new column (let's say email), also using a migration. Now if I wipe my database and re run the migrations, typeorm will complain no column named `email` found in `User`. I guess it loads the `User` entity when running query builder, is there a way to tell typeorm not to load the entity and just create the sql query based on what is provided in query builder.

Comment: i think Entity Manger API
https://typeorm.io/#/entity-manager-api
currently i have similar situation, i am trying to find solution myself